# Use React App (with NodeJS Backend) in own network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, public

I've got a react app (latest React version) with a NodeJS backend.
That runs so far locally. But now I want to use this React App (together with its NodeJS backend) with other devices in my home network.

How to do that?

That is my package.json of the React App:

```
 {
  "name": "dionysiscontrolcenter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.4",
    "eslint": "5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.15.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.10",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.0",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --env.mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --colors --profile --progress --env.mode=production",
    "build:analyze": "webpack --colors --profile --progress --env.mode=production --env.analyze=true",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/ --ext .js,.jsx"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  const config = {
    entry: ['./src/main.less', './src/main.jsx'],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, `./html/${env.branch || 'master'}`),
      filename: 'dionysiscontrolcenter.js',
      library: 'dionySisControlCenter',
      libraryExport: 'default',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    mode: env.mode || 'development',
    devtool: 'eval',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ hash: false, template: './index.hbs' }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'dev/static/', to: 'static/' },
        'dev/index.html',
      ]),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                import: false,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
              options: {
                gifsicle: {
                  interlaced: false,
                },
                optipng: {
                  optimizationLevel: 7,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(svg)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
          use: 'file-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
    watchOptions: {
      poll: 1500,
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dev/'),
      watchContentBase: true,
      disableHostCheck: true,
      // host: '0.0.0.0',
      inline: true,
      port: 8000,
      // public: process.env.webpack_public_address || null,
      overlay: true,
    },
  };

  if (env.mode === 'development') {
    // blabla alias
    config.entry.unshift(
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      'react-hot-loader/patch'
    );
    config.resolve.alias = { 'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom' };
    config.module.rules.unshift({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      options: {
        failOnError: env.mode === 'production',
      },
    });
  }

  if (env.analyze === 'true') {
    config.plugins.push(
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'static',
      })
    );
  }

  return config;
};
```

What I tried so far:

- Commented in host: '0.0.0.0' in the webpack.config.js
- Added the line: "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --env.mode=development --host 0.0.0.0", to scripts attribute in the package.json
- Removed --hot parameter in the scripts attribute of "dev" command

Can someone help here?

Comment: Have you tried adding host as well? To define your local IP address you need to add host as well like host: '192.168.1.2' in the devServer object.

Comment: Tried:

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --env.mode=development --host 192.168.0.10"}
But still no luck..

Comment: It is preferred if you could add this in your webpack's config file.

Comment: You can also do `webpack-dev-server --disable-host-check` to bypass host checking functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try to add HOST=0.0.0.0 to script object

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 webpack-dev-server --hot --env.mode=development",
  "build": "HOST=0.0.0.0 webpack --colors --profile --progress --env.mode=production",
  "build:analyze": "webpack --colors --profile --progress -- env.mode=production --env.analyze=true",
  "lint": "eslint ./src/ --ext .js,.jsx"
}
```